# How to write a file in ruby without a terminating newline

Tags: ruby

For debugging purposes, I want to alter a rake test so as *not* to end a saved file with a newline.

I don't know ruby. How do I do this? (`file.print` doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: What does "seem" mean? Does it work or doesn't it work? And what does "doesn't work" mean? What is your input, what is your desired output, what is your actual output, what is your program, what do you expect to happen, what actually happens, what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not clear what you are doing, but since you tried `file.print`, it looks like you have access to what is to be printed. Let's say this is `string`. My guess is that `string` already has a newline character. Then do:

```
file.print(string.chomp)
```